# Name Extension in AppleScript Not Working

Tags: applescript

I am trying to display the extension for a file that I choose. What am I doing wrong?

```
    set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select a file to transfer:")
    set ext to name extension of theFile
    display dialog ext as text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "System Events" to set ext to name extension of theFile
```

Answer (score 1):

tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to choose file {}
    set ext to name extension of theFile
    display dialog "la extenxion es  " & ext
end tell

Comment: Generally, when given a choice between System Events and Finder, System Events is faster. Also choose file does not need to be included within the tell block.